# How can I make this query not return lines with the same Unit ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that uses a CTE and pulls data like this.

My Results:

```
Mach    ProdDate    ActionCode  UnitID     RejectID    Wgt  
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AD              508.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AD              1016.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AE              508.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AE              1016.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AF              603.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AF              1206.0000
```

Desired Results:

```
Mach    ProdDate    ActionCode  UnitID     RejectID    Wgt  
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AD              508.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AE              508.0000
RW01    2015-08-28  Gross     215H0712AF              603.0000
```

Now here is my problem. I need to find a way to make my query NOT return multiples of the same Unit ID. I am not sure how to do this. As you can see below I tried using `distinct` but there are other columns that I am not pulling that are different. Which causes `distinct` to pull the same ID again. Having the same ID more than once screws up the total weight when I sum them up.

```
cteGROSS (UnitID, Time, Mach, Cte, ActionCode, RejectID, Wgt, ProdDate) AS
(
  SELECT
     distinct unit_id                 AS UnitID,
     sq_timestamp                     AS Time,
     (machine_type + machine_id)      AS Mach,
     'cteGross'                       AS Cte,
     'Gross'                          AS ActionCode,
     reject_id                        AS RejectID,
     SUM(wgt_scaled)                  AS Wgt,
     @ProdDate

  FROM MillProdDb.millproddb.dbo.invent_audit_cbs1

  WHERE
     CAST(sq_timestamp AS DATE) = @ProdDate         AND
     machine_type + machine_id in ('RW01','RW02','RW31','RW32') AND
     mx_station in ('RW','WINDER','REWINDER','CHECKER') AND
     wgt_scaled <> '0'

  GROUP BY
     unit_id,
     sq_timestamp,
     machine_type,
     machine_id,
     reject_id
),
```

I am fairly new to SQL and very new to the concept of CTEs, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like a great candidate for group by and aggregate functions. If you showed desired results we could say for sure

Comment: its nothing matter with CTE but with Group by

Comment: do you know how I would fix it? I thought it was the Group by as well. That's why I put the unit_id first. But that doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: just do a group by including all the stuff. The fact that you don't care about a certain column, well ignore it !

Comment: so which record you want to get when `UnitID` = 215H0712AD? first one `Wgt = 508` or  `Wgt = 1016` ? and why?

Comment: MySQL does not support CTEs.  Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: You give example output, but not the input data that created it.  Your code's column names do not match your example output.  Your SELECT column names do not match your CTE definition's column names.  You select `(machine_type + machine_id)` but group by `machine_type, machine_id`.  You're using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in one query.  You've tagged it as `MySQL` but use syntax `MySQL` does not support *(CTEs)*.

Comment: where does sum factor into your desired results. Sounds like you want the first row per grouping based on your Question [edit]

Comment: I am working on the reporting and auditing for the factory machines. I only need the first weight of the Unit ID, because sometimes they have to go back and re-weigh some things. This then puts another entry in the database.

Comment: fair enough. Do you have a primary key like an incrementing id. Also your proddate could benefit from being a datetime

Answer (score 0):

As you're making corrections it's becoming clearer as to your mistake(s).

You have `GROUP BY sq_timestamp` and `WHERE CAST(sq_timestamp AS DATE) = @ProdDate`.

My bet is that you have three records in your table for each `UnitID`, two with the same `sq_timestamp` and one with a different `sq_timestamp`.

You appear to have two choices here:
1.  Don't `GROUP BY sq_timestamp`
2.  Instead `GROUP BY CAST(sq_timestamp AS DATE)`

Then you will likely get just one row per `UnitID`.

But even then the `SUM(wgt)` won't give the results you want.  Maybe you want the `AVG(wgt)` of all the records, or the `MAX(wgt)`, or perhp you should just `GROUP BY wgt`?  Your question is not clear on that point.

Finally, you have potential source of issue;
- `SELECT (machine_type + machine_id)`
- `GROUP BY machine_type, machine_id`

This can be a problem when you have values like `'RW0' + '1'` and `'RW' + '01'`.  Your `GROUP BY` will keep them separate, but then after they're concatenated in your `SELECT` they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the min(wgt)

```
      with tbl(Mach    ,ProdDate,    ActionCode,  UnitID  ,   RejectID,    Wgt  ) as
      ( select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AD','',508.0000 from dual union
      select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AD','',1016.0000 from dual union
      select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AE','',508.0000 from dual union
      select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AE','',1016.0000 from dual union
      select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AF','',508.0000 from dual union
      select 'RW01','2015-08-28','Gross','215H0712AF','',1206.0000 from dual),
      dist as
      (select distinct(unitID) as dist_id,min(WGT) as min_wgt from tbl
      group by unitID)
      select tbl.* from dist,tbl
      where dist.dist_id = tbl.UnitID
      and dist.min_wgt=tbl.Wgt
```

Output

```
      MACH, PRODDATE, ACTIONCODE, UNITID,   REJECTID, WGT
      RW01  2015-08-28  Gross   215H0712AD           508
      RW01  2015-08-28  Gross   215H0712AE           508
      RW01  2015-08-28  Gross   215H0712AF           508
```